# Get parent node in angular recursion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue about angular recursion. I tried to get parent, but not work.
My code is pushed on Plunker, maybe some longer.

My target is when page start loaded, it will auto check the parent checkbox dynamically from checked checkbox.

For example, When page start loaded, the checkbox of「Visa Dcc (M)」, it will auto check the 「Visa Dcc」 and 「Credit Card...」 until the parent is null or nothing.

The code is include 3 object -> obj1, obj2, obj3.

obj1 -> It is a all tender

obj2 -> It is include child id and parent id to decide obj1's tender to make the tree list

obj3 -> It is a already available tender of tree list checkbox is checked.

```
   function recursiveCheck (current, treelist, parent) {
        var parentCach = parent;
        var subTenderCach = [];
        angular.forEach(treelist, function(value, key) {
            if (value.parentTenderId == parentCach.tender.primaryKey) {
                angular.forEach(current, function(value1, key1){
                    if (value.childTenderId == value1.tender.primaryKey) {
                        var childTender = recursiveCheck(current, treelist, value1);
                        value1.subTender = childTender;
                        var t = angular.copy(value1);
                        t.parentTenderKey = parentCach.tender.primaryKey;
                        t.parentObj = parentCach;
                        t.currentObj = t.tender.name;
                        angular.forEach($scope.tenderListAvailable, function(value2, key2){
                            if (value2.primaryKey == t.primaryKey) {
                                console.log(t);
                                parentCach.isCheck = true;
                                t.isCheck = true;
                            }
                        })
                        subTenderCach.push(t);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
        return subTenderCach;
    }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yrG9Nhb0bCb2ICWRUrtY?p=preview)

Comment: You haven't explained what the actual problem is or what steps in that demo we need to use to see the problem. See [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl My actual problem is first line text, i think you need check this plunker if understand my issue such as what parent node i can not get.

Comment: Went to demo and all I see is a bunch of checkboxes. It doesn't suggest what the issue is or what problem you are having. We can't help when you aren't specific enough for us to understand problem